# Cauchy integral formula, but singularities not inside and on the contour $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I encounter, perhaps too basic, question on my homework. It says this:

If $C$ is the circle $|z|=3$ described in the positive sense and if $\displaystyle{g(z_0)=\int_C\frac{2z^2-2z-2}{z-z_0}}\,dz$ show that $g(2)=8\pi i$. What is the value of $g(z_0)$ when $|z_0|>3$?

I understand that $g(2)$ can be easily evaluated using Cauchy integral formula since $f(z)=2z^2-2z-2$ analytic inside and on $C$, but I found no easy solution for the $|z_0|>3$ case.

Am I supposed to take parameter of $C$, do substitution and integrate over $[0,2\pi]$, or there exist any easier way to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should look at the singularities of  the ratio

$$\frac{2z^2-2z-2}{z-2}$$

and not focusing your attention *only* on the numerator. If $C$ is the given circle of radius $3$, then by Cauchy's residue theorem you can find the value of $g(2)$ quite easily.
Just check whether the zero of the monomial $z-2$ lies in the domain bounded by $C$...

If $|z_0|>3$, the analysis is similar, with an interesting outcome.

Comment: Do you need more details?

Comment: Perhaps I need a confirmation: is the answer is zero? I think using residue theorem, $g(z_0)=0$ because, well, no residue inside and on $C$, so the answer is 0.

Comment: I would say so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : If $|z_0|>3$, $z\mapsto \dfrac{2z^2-2z-2}{z-z_0}$ is analytic on $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<|z_0|\}$, and $C\subset U$.

You can also read this page : http://companal.wiki-site.com/index.php/Winding_number_version_of_Cauchy_integral_formula